# Broken "go get it" link for "Strunk & White" on meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, per-site-meta, 404-not-found

"go get it" link for "Strunk & White" badge on ruSO.meta refers to [404 page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts):

> [image: go get it RU]

Same on enSO

> [image: same button on enSO]

Also redirect to 404, because not available/exist Loq Quality Queue

> [image: available review queue on meta]

Comment: Reproduced on Meta.SO (English). Meta sites don't have Low Quality Posts review queues, which is where "Go get it" links to, so you get a 404 when clicking it on any meta site.

Comment: @Aurora0001 , then it's become bug and must be removed from StackExchange to improve the quality of StackExchange website .

Comment: related on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341997/copy-editor-badge-go-get-it-redirects-to-non-existing-queue-on-meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fair point. I pushed a change to remove the "go get it" link on child metas. With you in the next prod build.

Comment: Next build is > `rev 2017.1.26.24822`. right?

Comment: @rene should be, yeah

Comment: sorry to bother you again but I expected this fix would be applied to all cases where it goes to review queues on meta, like the on for [copy editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=topactivity) (as reported by me [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341997/copy-editor-badge-go-get-it-redirects-to-non-existing-queue-on-meta)) but that doesn't seem to be the case. Does it help if I create separate bug reports for each badge so you can keep track of which ones are done. I'm not trying to push the 6 to 8 weeks or so. I'm trying be helpful.

Comment: @rene Is it just the LQ queue that's causing problems? Or are there other ones that you're aware of? No need for separate reports per badge; I have IDE search at my disposal to find 'em. :)

Comment: Based on what I have seen now, I would say yes. I hoped you would use Visual Studio to save me from finding all these links ;)

Comment: @rene Turns out, Copy Editor is the only other badge that does this. I pushed the change; it'll be live in the next build (> 2017.1.27.24833).

Comment: Great, you're awesome!

Comment: @AdamLear Not only copy editor, Research Assistant is also causing problems in redirection, [“Go get it” link is broken for Research Assistant and some other badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310891/357396). Clicking on it redirects to tag preferences in our profile page.