# "Go get it" link is broken for Research Assistant and some other badges

Tags: bug, profile-page, edit-badges, redirection, activity

In our profile's activity, we are shown our recent badge earned and shows next possible badge we can earn. We can also  select which badge's progress to show. On some sites (I tested on Hinduism, Movies&TV and Vegetarianism), I have noticed that clicking on "Go get it" for "Research Assistant" redirects to preferences page in our profile settings. To be precise, It redirects to "favorite tag preferences"

[image: gif showing redirection to manage personalized prediction instead of Tags page]

If I am not wrong, it should redirect to "Tags" page of respective site. However, this is normal on many sites and redirects to Tags page (Tested on Meta Stack Exchange, English Language & Learners, Ask Ubuntu, Arqade).

**Edit**: Clicking on "Go Get it" for Copy Editor badge in activity redirects to Low Quality Posts review queue.

I would like to know the reason behind the redirection to profile page (in case of Research Assistant) and review queue (for Copy Editor).

Answer (score 2):

### Research Assistant

It has been this way since February 13, 2015. (Friday the 13th, in fact.)  Prior to that, there was no "Go Get It" URL for this tag and no explanation exists beyond the commit message "Top boxes - more link targets for earned badges".

The exact logic is: if the user has any favorite tags, go to the list of favorite tags, otherwise, go to `/tags`.  I expect the logic was that users would be best equipped to edit wikis for tags they're interested in.  The UI here just isn't great at conveying that message.  I don't really know what the best course of action is here, since the list of top tags probably isn't a good starting place either.  Maybe [`/users/current?tab=tags`](/users/current?tab=tags) since those are the tags the user is most knowledgeable in.

### Copy Editor

Copy Editor was set in the same commit as Research Assistant.  It takes users to the low quality queue if they have the editing privilege and the site has a low quality queue.  Otherwise there is no link.

I agree with Glorfindel that this makes sense as a place to send users, it is a source of posts that could probably use an editing eye.

Answer (score 1):

> Clicking on "Go Get it" for Copy Editor badge in activity redirects to Low Quality Posts review queue.
>
> I would like to know the reason behind it.

Well, we don't want to encourage people editing random posts and bumping them, do we? There isn't any better list of posts which might benefit from editing than the Low Quality Posts review queue; one of the options is to <kbd>Edit</kbd> the post. Conveniently, the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege also grants access to the Low Quality Posts review queue.

<sub>BTW, I cannot reproduce your problem with the Research Assistant badge on Movies & TV. For me, it redirects to https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags as expected. However, on Stack Overflow, I experience the same issue as you.</sub>

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I originally posted question about Research assistant badge. My main question was about that. Later, I found out there is an issue with Copy Editor also. So, I added it in the second revision. That "I would like to know the reason"  is misleading I think.  So, I wanted to know the reason about the misbehaviour of the redirection on both the cases. This redirection takes place in SO. It still takes me to profile page. Can you try it on a site where you have edit privileges and not a mod?

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce the issue on Stack Overflow. I knew the [bug] with Research Assistant was more important for you, but I couldn't ... eh ... resist ... providing a motivation for the second question (which is one of the reason you shouldn't ask two questions at once :))