# Alignment issue in the Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There is an alignment issue in the [**Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) page, under the **Tags** section the **Add** buttons has extra height.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Alignment issue in the Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences page]

The alignment issue is in all the Stack Exchange main and meta sites. Not sure this is due to the impact of the recent [left nav change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/312043).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been fixed in production:

[image: Tag inputs, sans bottom margins]

Comment: Is it anyway related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310891/357396) report? I think so because same page i.e tag preferences is involved both. I may not be right though.

Comment: @NogShine It's not related, but I'll raise the issue with someone on the team.