# Remove "Go get it" for Research Assistant

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, badge-progress, edit-badges

This request is a follow up to my question ["Go get it" link is broken for Research Assistant and some other badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310891/357396).

I found out from Brain Nickel's answer that it is not a bug but intended behaviour. When we click on Go get it, we are redirected to tag notification section in our preferences. If there are no watched tags, it takes us to [Tags](/tags).

Brian Nickel explained logic behind this in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311135/357396):

> The exact logic is: if the user has any favorite tags, go to the list of favorite tags, otherwise, go to /tags. I expect the logic was that users would be best equipped to edit wikis for tags they're interested in.

But there is a problem here. In spite of detailed wikis, we are still redirected to wikis. Even if we submit a detailed wiki when there is no wiki, the result is same. We are redirected to watched tags.

This is not helpful. Having Go get it link serves no purpose if that happens. Hence I propose two possible solutions.

1. Redirecting all the users to tags section irrespective of watched tags.
2. Removing 'go get it' option from Research assistant.

Select a better option between two. In my opinion, second one seems plausible as it reduces strain on database.