# "Go get it" button on editing badges has been removed on all other sites; should it be removed on this site too?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, meta, edit-badges

On Meta Stack Exchange, when tracking any of the editing badges ([Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor), [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), or [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor)), opening the progress dialog shows a button to "Go get it". Upon clicking, you're redirected to the Low Quality Posts review queue.

I'm aware that this button used to lead to a [404 error on child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290309/broken-go-get-it-link-for-strunk-white-on-meta-site) and was removed on those as a result. I am also aware that the button has also been removed on main Q&A sites, as displayed in the screenshot for my Stack Overflow profile below:

[image: Screenshot of SO progress popup]

This leaves Meta Stack Exchange as the last site to still feature this button.

Should this button also be removed on MSE? It doesn't really make sense for this button to redirect to the Low Quality Posts review queue, especially since a task there rarely pops up, and since it's been removed from all other sites, it should probably be removed here as well.

Quick demonstration .gif, not that it's really needed:

[image: Gif of pressing the Go get it button]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We haven't removed that button from main sites.

You don't have the Edit privilege on Stack Overflow, so you can't access the Low Quality review queue and therefore don't see the button, but users who meet the rep threshold for that (usually 2000 rep; 1000 on sites still in public beta) do:

[image: screenshot from my local dev environment showing the "Go get it" button]

Comment: Hoho! Any reason why it redirects to LQP?

Comment: @Spevacus I believe the original theory was that the LQ queue would be a place where you could likely find stuff that could benefit from an edit.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the explanation, apologies for the not so useful bug report. Cheers!

Comment: @Spevacus Guess you're in the same boat as me...until SE re-valued question upvotes at 10 rep instead of 5, Meta.SE was the sole site I ever held editing privileges on.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Heh, yeah, it's exhausting to look for opportunities to contribute on SO. Contrary to the norm, I quite like participating on meta. The site (and network) is so interestingly developed and managed, I love learning more about it.