# Improve alignment of "Learn more" button in "Newest badge" popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

The popup when you click on your newest badge in your user profile has a "Learn more" button, but its alignment is suboptimal; it's too close to the top of its container:

[image]

It looks better with a 4px top margin:

[image]

Comment: Didn't Aaron just fix this two days ago? Ah, it was the "Go get it" box. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348944/284336 Guess we've got more buttons to fix. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Misallignement in next priviledge tooltip?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398041/4642212). Or are the different buttons for _badges_ and _privileges_ not tracked in the same issue?

Comment: @Catija [I can still reproduce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLBx0.jpg)

Comment: I was going to report the exact same issue. (I'm on the latest Chrome.)

Comment: This seems to have been solved during this week.

Comment: @bad_coder for the 'Next badge' (or perhaps it was working already), not for the 'Newest badge'. At least for me (Firefox, macOS).

Comment: @Glorfindel you are right, I had only checked [for this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398041) which being similar did turn out to be orthogonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The padding on the [Learn more] button has been fixed, and is now consistent with the padding on the [Go get it] button for the Next Badge popup.

> Go to your profile
> Want to learn more 'bout new badge?
> Button padding sweet