# "Learn more" buttons are misaligned in the next privilege info panel

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, user-interface

**Addressing the duplicate**:

This was closed as a dupe of [Improve alignment of "Learn more" button in "Newest badge" popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349013/622284) and while that is [most certainly fixed now (screenshot taken today)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LXLK.png), this specific button is still misaligned. Here's a screenshot that I took today:

[image: Screenshot of learn more button still being skewed]

As such, I don't believe this is a duplicate any longer, and can be reopened as its own bug report, given that the "Newest badge" popup's button is aligned correctly now and this one isn't.

---

**Directly related:** ["Go get it" button is misaligned in badge progress box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348934/622284)

The "Learn more..." button in the profile page's next privilege tracker is aligned to the left instead of the right.

Screenshot:

[image: Picture of the Learn more button's misalignment]

Looks like another user interface regression, which [Aaron Shekey mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348944/622284) in a fix to a similar issue.

Could this be fixed as well?

Comment: @Catija the other one is about vertical alignment,this one about horizontal. Very related, but not exactly the same, each is a different CSS rule. Can you please re-consider the closure?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I'd argue this one is about both vertical and horizontal. More notably, this one is about the Next Privilege popup, whereas the linked one is about the Next Badge popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like it's been fixed!

[image: Image of the privilege popout card, now with correct spacing around the Learn more button]

Much better!

Since I'm *pretty* confident that Yaakov Ellis fixed it, I'll post a haiku in his honor, and hope he has a [relaxing sabbatical](https://twitter.com/Yaakov/status/1374823666257641479):

> New milestone soon
> Want to learn more about it
> Button needed space

Comment: +1 for the haiku ;)  Large bugs need sonnets.