# Improve alignment of "Learn more" button in "Next privilege" popup

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, popups

The alignment of the "Learn more" button in the "Next privilege" popup is not really well aligned with the edge of the black square:

[image]

It is also too close to the text showing how near you are to your next privilege.  Compared to the next badge popup:

[image]

The former's alignment is suboptimal.  I think it would look better 5, maybe 6px away from the edge, and the same horizontally.  Or can we just make it a bit more like the "Next badge" menu?

Comment: Also, I already asked this, and had it closed as a dupe of the proposed dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349303/learn-more-buttons-are-misaligned-in-the-next-privilege-info-panel