# Badge popup padding bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, regression

When clicking on a badge in the *Activity* screen tab of my profile, the button is misaligned. The padding which used to exist above it has disappeared, and it's now on the left side of the popup.

Stack Overflow screenshot of next tracked badge in dark mode:

[image: Stack Overflow screenshot]

Super User screenshot of next tag badge:

[image: Super User screenshot]

MSE screenshot of newest awarded badge:

[image]

This is still present as of 23 Dec

Comment: Huh. Regression of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348934/go-get-it-button-is-misaligned-in-badge-progress-box)? Also [this report is related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349013/622284).

Comment: You could be right, it looks similar. There is no longer a counter, and no right chevron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed!

[image]