# "Go get it" button for editing badges should link to the 'Annotated Posts' page

Tags: feature-request, edits, badge-progress, post-notices, edit-badges

If I'm tracking one of the edit badges and click on the progress bar, it offers me a link to 'go get it':

> [image: ![enter image description here]

Clicking on the button takes me to the Low-Quality Posts review queue. It's actually quite a sensible idea, because:

> The original theory was that the LQ queue would be a place where you could likely find stuff that could benefit from an edit. [[link]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348541/go-get-it-button-on-editing-badges-has-been-removed-on-all-other-sites-should#comment1166214_348552)

As [Glorfindel explains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310895/1278220), there's another reason that this link is provided:

> We don't want to encourage people editing random posts and bumping them, do we? There isn't any better list of posts which might benefit from editing than the Low Quality Posts review queue; one of the options is to <kbd>Edit</kbd> the post.

I can think of one another list of posts that might benefit from edits- the '[Annotated Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107142/1278220)' page. ([https://[site].stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?page=1&tab=noticed](https://%5Bsite%5D.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?page=1&tab=noticed))

The page actually shows *all* posts with notices- controversial posts, bountied posts, etc., but the bulk of the posts on that list are the ones with the *'Want to improve this post?'* notice. (Perhaps a feature that allowed users to 'sort by message' could be added to help out with this)

One advantage of this is that *all* users, irrespective of rep-level, can access this page. Currently, the go-get-it button is [only present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348541/go-get-it-button-on-editing-badges-has-been-removed-on-all-other-sites-should#comment1166214_348552) for users who have the edit/access-LQP-review privilege.

Another advantage is that the LQP review queue is often empty, particularly on sites that have a healthy number of reviewers. However, the 'Annotated Posts' page is quite consistently full of improvable posts.

**Feature request: Please have the go-get-it button for edit-badges link to the 'Annotated Posts' page**

Comment: This really depends on how mods put post notices on their sites. I just tested this page on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed), and the majority are posts recognized by a Collective member or bountied posts. I doubt SO mods have enough time to put "Need citation" post notices now... The filter, on the other hand, should be a great addition.